# Find the index of first matching string from string array or list c#

Tags: c#, regex

I Have string in the form

```
var dummyString = $@"SIGNED APPLICATION AND AFFIDAVIT REQUIRED  LOCATION:  BLK 99, LOT 9 AND BLK 100 LOT 9, 10, 11, 12 & 13 RT 38 EAST HAINESPORT, NJ  BASED ON:  VACANT LAND";
```

What I would like to do is to extract the location/address from this string. I can easily find the index of the **LOCATION:** but can't think of of efficient solution for the index where i should terminate the string. The easiest option is to iterate over the list and find the index of a state code but this won't be very efficient way of handling it.

What i thought would be the solution to this problem is to use a list of US state codes and then find the index of the first match of any state code after the index of *LOCATION:* substring with a whitespace so I can find the complete state code and its index.

```
public const List<string> USStateCodes = new List<string> { "AL", "AK", "AS", "AZ", "AR", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DE", "DC", "FM", "FL", "GA", "GU", "HI", "ID", "IL", "IN", "IA", "KS", "KY", "LA", "ME", "MH", "MD", "MA", "MI", "MN", "MS", "MO", "MT", "NE", "NV", "NH", "NJ", "NM", "NY", "NC", "ND", "MP", "OH", "OK", "OR", "PW", "PA", "PR", "RI", "SC", "SD", "TN", "TX", "UT", "VT", "VI", "VA", "WA", "WV", "WI", "WY" };
```

Any idea on how to proceed from here?

The output i want is:

> BLK 99, LOT 9 AND BLK 100 LOT 9, 10, 11, 12 & 13 RT 38 EAST HAINESPORT, NJ

The problem stated here is part of bigger logic where I use regex to find the index of zip code (5 digits) as terminator but in some cases, the zip code may not be present in address (user error). I still have to be able to extract the address.

Comment: *but can't think of of efficient solution for the index where i should terminate the string.* index of "BASED ON:" ?

Comment: I could do a for loop for each state code in list and try to find index of the code in the string....but that requires iterating over every item...not very elegant.

Comment: Would probably need regex

Comment: `SIGNED APPLICATION AND AFFIDAVIT REQUIRED  LOCATION:` and `BASED ON:  VACANT LAND` remain same always in the input string?

Comment: No....its a variable value...it keeps on changing except LOCATION is present all the times.

Comment: then find index of location and find index of state and get substring out of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
var dummyString = @"SIGNED APPLICATION AND AFFIDAVIT REQUIRED  LOCATION:  BLK 99, LOT 9 AND BLK 100 LOT 9, 10, 11, 12 & 13 RT 38 EAST HAINESPORT, NJ  BASED ON:  VACANT LAND";
var USStateCodes = new List<string> { "AL", "AK", "AS", "AZ", "AR", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DE", "DC", "FM", "FL", "GA", "GU", "HI", "ID", "IL", "IN", "IA", "KS", "KY", "LA", "ME", "MH", "MD", "MA", "MI", "MN", "MS", "MO", "MT", "NE", "NV", "NH", "NJ", "NM", "NY", "NC", "ND", "MP", "OH", "OK", "OR", "PW", "PA", "PR", "RI", "SC", "SD", "TN", "TX", "UT", "VT", "VI", "VA", "WA", "WV", "WI", "WY" };
var result = Regex.Match(dummyString, $@"LOCATION:\s*(.*?\b(?:{string.Join("|", USStateCodes)}))\b")?.Groups[1].Value;
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/nWhZuj), `result` output: `BLK 99, LOT 9 AND BLK 100 LOT 9, 10, 11, 12 & 13 RT 38 EAST HAINESPORT, NJ`.

The resulting pattern is

```
LOCATION:\s*(.*?\b(?:AL|AK|AS|AZ|AR|CA|CO|CT|DE|DC|FM|FL|GA|GU|HI|ID|IL|IN|IA|KS|KY|LA|ME|MH|MD|MA|MI|MN|MS|MO|MT|NE|NV|NH|NJ|NM|NY|NC|ND|MP|OH|OK|OR|PW|PA|PR|RI|SC|SD|TN|TX|UT|VT|VI|VA|WA|WV|WI|WY))\b
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=LOCATION%3A%5Cs*%28.*%3F%5Cb%28%3F%3AAL%7CAK%7CAS%7CAZ%7CAR%7CCA%7CCO%7CCT%7CDE%7CDC%7CFM%7CFL%7CGA%7CGU%7CHI%7CID%7CIL%7CIN%7CIA%7CKS%7CKY%7CLA%7CME%7CMH%7CMD%7CMA%7CMI%7CMN%7CMS%7CMO%7CMT%7CNE%7CNV%7CNH%7CNJ%7CNM%7CNY%7CNC%7CND%7CMP%7COH%7COK%7COR%7CPW%7CPA%7CPR%7CRI%7CSC%7CSD%7CTN%7CTX%7CUT%7CVT%7CVI%7CVA%7CWA%7CWV%7CWI%7CWY%29%29%5Cb&i=SIGNED%20APPLICATION%20AND%20AFFIDAVIT%20REQUIRED%20%20LOCATION%3A%20%20BLK%2099%2C%20LOT%209%20AND%20BLK%20100%20LOT%209%2C%2010%2C%2011%2C%2012%20%26%2013%20RT%2038%20EAST%20HAINESPORT%2C%20NJ%20%20BASED%20ON%3A%20%20VACANT%20LAND).

**Details**

- `LOCATION:` - a fixed starting string
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(.*?\b(?:{string.Join("|", USStateCodes)}))` - Group 1 (the result will be captured in the group):

  - `.*?` - any 0 or more chars other than newline chars (use `RegexOptions.Singleline` to match newlines, too), as few as possible
  - `\b` - a word boundary
  - `(?:{string.Join("|", USStateCodes)})` - creates an alternation group with the state codes (like `(?:AL|AK|AS|...|WY)`) and matches any one of the alternatives
- `\b` - a word boundary.

Comment: Very close but it seems to be missing the state code.

Comment: No, it is there. See the demo.

Comment: You are life saver!